# Is there a better way of making the code I made? char array, keylisteners

Tags: arrays, input, char, keylistener

I want to make a dialog box popup when I press a letter on the keyboard. This way I made it, I have a really long char array. Is there a better way to make this code?

```
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}; 
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        char a = alphabet[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length;i++) {
            a = alphabet[i];
            if(c == a)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Error: "+c, " cannot be used", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex for any single lowercase character would be less code, if your definition of better is less lines.

```
private String _regex = "[a-z]";
private Pattern _lowercaseCharacterPattern = Pattern.compile(_regex);

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    char c = e.getKeyChar();
    if( _lowercaseCharacterPattern.matcher(String.valueOf(c) ).matches() )
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Error: "+c, " cannot be used", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, you could use `.contains()` on a `String` of 'valid' characters.

Something like:

```
    private final String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();            

        // if the character entered is not the list of valid inputs, warn user 
        if( !letters.contains(Character.toString(c)) ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Error: "+c, " cannot be used", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```